# Что такое постинкремент и прединкремент?

Tags: javascript, php

Я изучаю javascript и php, но не понимаю полностью такие моменты как постинкремент и прединкремент. Объясните, если не трудно.

Answer (score 4):

Инкремент: Операция увелечения(приращения) в `C` подобных языках обычно на единицу (оператор `++`)
Декремент: Операция уменьшения в `C` подобных языках обычно на единицу (оператор `--`)
Прединкремент:

```
++i;
```

сначала выполняет инкремент а потом возвращает результат:

```
var i = 2;
alert(++i); // Выводит 3
```

а Постинкремент:

```
i++;
```

сначала возвращяет результат а потом выполняет инкремент:

```
var i = 2;
alert(i++); // Выводит 2
// а теперь i = 3;
```

P.S:
Уважаемый [[@Reyuzaki2](/users/7810/reyuzaki2)](/users/7810/reyuzaki2) как я понял из вашего комментария на ответ [[@aramcpp](/users/7796/aramcpp)](/users/7796/aramcpp) вы не знаете даже основ JavaScript, советую зайти и почитать:
1) На [javascript.ru](http://learn.javascript.ru/)
2) Особенно сюда: [Основные операторы JavaScript](http://learn.javascript.ru/main-operators)

чтоб подобных вопросов у вас больше не возникало :)

Comment: А кто сказал,что я изучил основы? =)

Comment: :) Ну просто написано "Я изучаю" я и подумал что дошли хотябы до главы про переменные :)

Answer (score 4):

```
a=++i => i=i+1
         a=i
--------------
a=i++ => a=i
         i=i+1
```

Comment: а вот это уже хороший ответ

Comment: всё,теперь можно продолжать изучение js

Comment: Хороший ответ от хорошего. :)

Comment: ахах,точно

Comment: Не совсем)

    a=++i => i=i+1
             a=i
    a=i++ => a=i
             i=i+1

Comment: незначительная помарка

Answer (score 1):

У прединкремента наивысший приоритет.
Например, есть код `a[++i]=5`,
то сначала инкрементируется, потом присваивается.
А так `a[i++]=5`
присваивается, потом инкреметируется.

Comment: То-есть,если
i=1;
если a=++i,то i инкрементируется в 2,потом присваивается ,a
если a=i++ ,то a присваивается 1,потом инкрементируется,но какой в этом смысл?

Comment: @Reyuzaki2 вы знаете основы JavaScript? у вас переменные в alert'e в апострофах а должны быть без!

Comment: @Reyuzaki2, смысл в том, что такие комбинации присвоений как "увеличить, адресовать" и наоборот "адресовать, увеличить" как и в обратную сторону часто встречаются в программах. Например определение длины строки оканчивающейся нулём: while(s[i++]!=0); длины идентификатора (на С): while(isalnum(s[i++])); и т.п.
В машинном языке процессоров могут быть предусмотрены соответствующие короткие команды для более быстрого выполнения этих комбинаций.