# JavaScript Инкремент

Tags: javascript

Изучаю JavaScript. В учебнике сказано:

> i++;      // более короткая запись для i = i + 1

Более короткая запись, как я понимаю делается для следующего:

*оптимизировать(сократить) код и сделать его понятнее; логично, что более короткая равна полной.*

Но я столкнулся с простым примером(в будущем назовем его **Пример№1**):

```js
i = 0;
while (i++ < 5) {
  alert(i);
}
```

И решил записать его, в не сокращенном виде (ведь они равны). У меня не получилось:

```js
i = 0;
while ((i = i + 1) < 5) {
  alert(i);
}
```

Из-за скобок приоритет меняется (с пятеркой сравнение идет уже после +1) и  последний алерт выдает четверку. Удивительно, что я не могу сделать полную запись, там где сделал сокращенную.

- Я хочу получить результат, как в **Пример№1**, но при этом сделать запись не сокращенную, а полную (т.е.`(i = i + 1)`)
- Постфиксная форма и префиксная форма, мне о них известно, они здесь роли не играют на мой взгляд. Если это важно вам кажется используйте их в своем объяснении.
- Такой вариант:

```js
i = 0;

while (i < 5) {
  i = i + 1;
  alert(i);
}
```

меня также не устраивает, нужно чтобы полная запись была в скобках у while, как и сокращенная.

**Мой вопрос:**

Объясните мне как это работает. **!** Нужно использовать цикл **while** как в моем примере, если записи равны, у вас не составит труда так записать. Ваше объяснение желательно пусть сводиться к следующему:

1. `i++; // более короткая запись для i = i + 1` Это неправда, записи не равны и ...
2. `i++; // более короткая запись для i = i + 1` Записи равны и ваш код(выше читаем какой результат я хочу получить) ...

**PS** Это не дубликат вопроса, пишу т.к. очередной пользователь ru.stackoverflow, пометил данный вопрос "как возможный дубликат". Данный вопрос хорошо оформлен и четко поставлен, были даны подробные ответы. Если в данном вопросе вы находите что-то знакомое и близкое, это не означает, что он становится дубликатом. Лучше прочитать вопрос еще раз, прочитать и комментарии к нему, а не писать ссылку на тему, которая уже здесь несколько раз поднималась. Данный вопрос отражает стремление разобраться, он понятен и несет пользу(автору уж точно).

Comment: "они здесь роли не играют" - как раз играют, `i++` - возвращает значение до инкремента.

Comment: @Igor Хорошо, уберу

Comment: Мой вопрос совершенно о другом vp_arth, какой дубликат?

Comment: Не вижу тут ничего не то, что совершенно, но и просто другого. Базовые понятия. Операторы.

Comment: @vp_arth Удивительно, заминусовали, в дубликат занесли. Где ответ, где код ваш? Вопрос четко поставлен, в чем проблема?

Comment: `while ((i = i + 1) <= 5){}` вас тоже не устраивает? Тогда `while ((i = i + 1) - 1 < 5){}`

Comment: @vp_arth Напишите ваш полный ответ пожалуйста, с объяснением. Если он будет мне понятен, я его приму.

Comment: На мой вкус, `++i` (надеюсь в JS такая запись тоже есть) ближе к `i = i + 1`. / Автор, один маленький совет на будущее. Сначала один раз *полностью читаете* тему и только *потом* (желательно еще и немного подумав) принимаетесь за экзерцизы.

Comment: @avp, присвоение имеет почти самый низший приоритет, так что будет или ошибка, или, если повезёт, аналог `i++`;

Comment: @Other, о каком присваивании идет речь? А поведение `while (++i < 5)` и `while ((i = i + 1) < 5)` (по крайней мере в Си) совпадает (цикл выполнится 4 раза), и оба они отличаются от `while (i++ < 5)` (5 раз)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Что такое постинкремент и прединкремент?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/120015/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82)

Comment: Не согласен что дубликат, вопрос шире и затрагивает новую проблему

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В данном случае имеет место неверное интерпретирование того, что написано в учебнике.

> ```
> i++; // более короткая запись для i = i + 1
> ```

Обрати внимание на `;` в этой записи.

Действительно, строка

```
i++;
```

может быть безболезненно заменена на

```
i = i + 1;
```

---

Особенность постинкремента в том, что данный оператор возвращает значение **до** увеличения. И, так как в строке `i++;` это значение нигде не используется, указанные выше записи становятся эквивалентны.

---

Если же возвращаемое значение используется, как в случае в вопросе, то здесь подойдет ответ [@good_web_master](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/120049/186999) наглядно демонстрирующий эквивалентные выражения:

```
a=i++ => a=i
         i=i+1
```

Как видно, для полной эмуляции *короткой* записи, необходимо где-то сохранять значение перед увеличением, это может быть:

1. сторонняя переменная

   ```js
   var i = 0,
     a;

   while ((a = i, i = i + 1, a) < 5) {
     console.log(i);
   }
   ```

   В данном случае помогает [оператор Запятая (`,`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) позволяя вернуть значение `a` для сравнения в условии.
2. непосредственно создаваемые структуры:

   1. объект

      ```js
      var i = 0;

      while ({pred:i, curr: i = i + 1}.pred < 5) {
        console.log(i);
      }
      ```
   2. либо массив

      ```js
      var i = 0;

      while ([i, i = i + 1][0] < 5) {
        console.log(i);
      }
      ```

Comment: Много лишних букв.

Comment: Добавь мои варианты из коммента. Про `<=5` хотя бы.

Comment: @vp_arth, лучше добавь своим ответом

Answer (score 6):

"они здесь роли не играют" - как раз играют:

`i++` - возвращает значение до инкремента, a

`i = i + 1` - после.

```js
var i = 0;
// здесь с единицей сравнивается значение i до инкремента - то есть 0
if (i++ < 1) {
  console.log("i - check " + i);
}

var j = 0;
// здесь с единицей сравнивается значение j после инкремента - то есть 1
if ((j = j + 1) < 1) {
} else {
  console.log("j - no check " + j);
}

// однако:
var k = 0;
// здесь с единицей сравнивается значение k после инкремента - то есть 1
if (++k < 1) {
} else {
  console.log("k - no check " + k);
}
```

*печатание цикла `while` в свете приобретенных знаний оставлено автору вопроса в качестве упражения*

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53632/discussion-on-answer-by-igor-javascript-).

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov, минусы не убираются, кроме, возможно, исключительных мер.

Comment: @Other Давайте не будем жмотиться, и проголосуем человеку за вопрос. Я - уже.

Comment: Где Ваши принципы, баронет?

Comment: @Other Я их берегу и зря не расходую!

Answer (score 5):

```
var i = 2;
i++;      // более короткая запись для i = i + 1.
alert(i); // 3
```

Именно в такой форме, не в качестве выражения, это и есть более короткая запись, потому что делает ровным счётом то же самое - увеличивает значение переменной `i` на единицу.

**В чём же разница?**
В возвращаемом значении.
Выражение `i++` возвращает значение переменной `i` до увеличения.
Выражение `(i=i+1)`(как и `++i`) возвращает значение переменной `i` после увеличения.

Существует множество способов привести второе выражение к первому, например:

- Сохранить первоначальное значение: `(temp = i, i = i + 1, temp)`
- Рассчитать первоначальное значение: `(i = i + 1) - 1`

```js
{ // Вариант с сохранением значения
  let i = 0, temp;
  while (temp = i, i = i + 1, temp < 5) console.log(i);
}

{ // Вариант с восстановлением значения
  let i = 0;
  while ((i = i + 1) - 1 < 5) console.log(i);
}

// Можно также произвести некоторые математические операции для упрощения
{ // Увеличим обе части неравенства на 1
  let i = 0;
  while ((i = i + 1) < 6) console.log(i);
}
{ // За счёт нестрогого неравенства можно сохранить первоначальную константу
  let i = 0;
  while ((i = i + 1) <= 5) console.log(i);
}
```