# Непонятный результат вычисления

Tags: c#

Почему в данном случае **a** будет равно 20, а не 21?

```
int a = 10;
a += a++;
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

Comment: `a += ++a;` -> в этом случае `a` будет равным `21`

Comment: это вопрос что такое пред-инкремент и пост-инкремент https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/120015/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82

Answer (score 13):

Это вариация классической задачи про `++i + ++i` в несколько упрощенном варианте.

В C++ - это undefined behavior, и результатом в большинстве компиляторов будет 21. Цитируя lurkmore:

> согласно стандартам С и С++, побочные эффекты (то есть инкремент в данном случае) могут быть применены в любой удобный для компилятора момент между двумя точками следования. Конструкцию i = ++i + ++i; компилятор вправе понять и как
>
> `tmp=i; tmp++; i = tmp; tmp++; i += tmp;`
>
> и как
>
> `tmp=i; tmp++; tmp++; i = tmp + tmp;`

Из-за непредсказуемости поведения этот пример раньше часто предлагали объяснить на собеседованиях :)

---

В C# результатом будет 20, т.к. порядок вычисления явно задан спецификацией. В C# нет никаких точек следования, компилятор не настолько свободен при оптимизации выражений, так что он вычисляет в том порядке, в котором ему приказали:

`+=` - это compound assignment operator. Он не самостоятельный оператор (не допускает отдельной перегрузки, и т.д.), а просто шорткат для

```
a = a + a++;
```

Т.е. он просто берет результат вычисления `a` (10), прибавляет к нему результат вычисления `a++` (10) и складывает сумму (20) обратно в `a`. При этом операнды вычисляются именно слева направо.

Процесс вычисления постфиксного оператора a++ описан в спецификации C#, 7.6.9 Postfix increment and decrement operators, и он следующий:

- Сохраняется текущее значение a. (10)
- Вызывается оператор (++) с передачей сохраненного значения a в качестве аргумента.
- Результат вычисления оператора (11) сохраняется в a. (которое позже перезатрется результатом сложения)
- Сохраненное значение a возвращается как результат операции. (10)

Поэтому

```
a + (a++) -> 20
(a++) + a -> 21
```

Comment: А мой коментарий с даной паралелью заминусили и удалили =( Добавив что у меня проблемы  логикой.

Comment: *Из-за непредсказуемости поведения этот пример раньше часто предлагали объяснить на собеседованиях* и на экзаменах по C++ )

Comment: @Andrew потому что в нем нет обоснования такого поведения :)

Comment: @DenisBubnov  Конечно непредсказуемый, ведь ответ зависит ОТ КОМИЛЯТОРА С++.

Comment: @Andrew да, но вопрос же про поведение именно в C#. А в нем все предсказуемо.

Comment: @PashaPash когда человек учится, он сначала пользуется общепринятой логикой, а потом уже логикой часной. Общепринятая логика подсказывает что там будет 21. Часная (относительно языка/компилятора) говорит что там будет 20.

Comment: @PashaPash а мой ответ Денису был исключительно в рамках его замечания-цитаты.

Comment: @Andrew моя логика всегда подсказывала что получится 20, так что ваша логика скорее всего не общепринятая :)

Answer (score 5):

Значение присвоения оператора инкремента не используется ни в одном из путей выполнения, что-то похожее скажет ReSharper на такой код `a += a++;` сообщение:

> Value assigned is not used in any execution path

Вы попросту потеряете свой постфиксный инкремент, так как он выполняется после того, как выполнится операция сложения и перед присваиванием. Вот если Вы используете префиксный инкремент, тогда получите в результате **21**.

```
int a = 10;
a += ++a;
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

Так как операция префиксного инкремента выполнится раньше, чем выполнится сложение и присваивание.

> В префиксной форме инкремент или декремент выполняется до
>   использования значения при вычислении выражения. В постфиксной форме инкремент или декремент выполняется после использования значения при вычислении выражения.

Ссылки:

- [Оператор ++ (справочник по C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/36x43w8w.aspx)
- [Оператор -- (Справочник по C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/wc3z3k8c.aspx)

Comment: Инкремент теряется потому что выполняется **до** присваивания. В противном случае результат был бы 11, а не 20.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, да, Вы правы, немного не так написал, сейчас исправлю.

Answer (score 3):

```
a += a++;
^---------- 10
     ^----- 10
      ^^--- 11
     ^^^--- значение 10, но a=11
  ^^------- 10+10 = 20
```